# Отдельное независимое позиционирование картинки от блока

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обводка это картинка. При нажатии на кнопку колесо вращается и обводка вместе с ним(так как она находится внутри блока). Как сделать так, чтобы картинка стала независимой и не вращалась. (При абсолютном позиционировании вне блока возникает проблема адаптивности)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нельзя вращать только нужные элементы, то вращайте картинку внутри на обратный угол от вращения родителя.